# Javascript with $(document).ready(function()

Tags: javascript

I am working with the library bootstrap-table.js of wenzhixin. If after loading the page I run $ ('p').click(function() works perfectly, the problem is if I use some function of the table filter, sort , etc. Then my function does not work.

I tried to change the order, jQuery.noConflict() but nothing.

I attached code.

Many thanks,

I am sorry my English.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Imputacion</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../clases/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../clases/bootstrap-table-develop/src/bootstrap-table.css">
  <script src="../clases/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../clases/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../clases/bootstrap-table-develop/src/bootstrap-table.js">      </script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('p').click(function() {
  alert("It is ok");
 });
 });
 </script>   
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
                <table id="table"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-show-columns="true"
           data-show-toggle="true"
           data-show-pagination-switch="true"
           data-show-refresh="true"
           data-search="true"
           data-pagination="true"
           data-key-events="true"
           class="table-condensed" style="font-size:0.85em;" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th data-field="codigo" data-sortable="true">codigo</th>
                <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Nombre</th>
                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true" style="text-align:center">Inicio</th>
                <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Horario</th>
                <th data-field="a" data-sortable="true">Acción</th>
                </tr>        
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>EMAK1RF015</td>
                    <td>Eugenio </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center">16:40</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>    
                        <a href="#" class="abreModalFinal" data-id='123456789' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Final" ><p>Eugenio</p></a>      
                            </td>
                    </tr>   
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are that some functions in your code ?

Comment: The functions are on the file bootstrap-table.js. It is a plugin for tables. If I use any function of this file, the rest stop works.

Comment: Does the bootstrap-table change the td-elements into <p>? Since you are using the $('p')?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. 
You mean that if I use bootstrap-table I can no use my own event handlers ?

Answer (score 0):

Elements are being added/updated later in the life cycle of your webpage, not when `DOMContent` is ready.

> Use [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('container').on('click', 'p', function() {
    alert("It is ok");
  });
});
```

Comment: It works. Many thanks!!!!!. My first answer in stackoverflow and I have been lucky enough to find an expert.

Comment: @EugenioDeDiego, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_